# Lasso selection performance

Tags: performance, algorithm

I'm the author of Leaflet plugin for lasso selection ([leaflet-lasso](https://github.com/zakjan/leaflet-lasso)). The lasso polygon consists of drawn mouse coordinates converted to lat/lng. When mouse is released, all map features are checked if they contain/intersect with the lasso polygon.

Unfortunately, users have performance issues with large number of map features, see example attached at [issue #24](https://github.com/zakjan/leaflet-lasso/issues/24).

I added checking for overlapping bounding boxes first, then calling the expensive contains/intersects method. It improved the performance with a small lasso polygon. However, with a large lasso polygon that surrounds all features, the performance improvement is none.

The current algorithm is available at https://github.com/zakjan/leaflet-lasso/blob/410c80bdf439cc66cc68cb38a43afe95b0fc2f24/src/calc.ts#L54-L85

I considered to use a spatial index such as [flatbush](https://github.com/mourner/flatbush). However, it doesn't give me any significant performance benefit, because it optimizes only the part of checking bounding boxes, which is fast enough already. The bottleneck is in the contains/intersects part of the algorithm.

I read PostGIS source code (ST_Contains/ST_Intersects) to see if it is doing anything smarter, but as far as I understood it, it seems it's doing the same, using a spatial index only to check bounding box.

Could you suggest me what might be the best option to improve overall performance?